# Combining data with SELECT clause with OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (col_1 INT, col_2 INT, col_3 INT, col_4 INT)

INSERT INTO table_1(col_1, col_2, col_3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.val_1, INSERTED.val_2, INSERTED.val_2, INSERTED.val_3, tab.val_4 INTO @Temp(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
SELECT tab.val_1,
    tab.val_2,
    tab.val_3
FROM table_2 AS tab
WHERE tab.something > 0
```

I need to insert values from table_2 to table_1 and @Temp table. The problem is table_1 doestn't have a column which is available in @Temp and I couldn't use find a way to use **OUTPUT** clause which should also use data from the **SELECT** clause used in table_2.

When I try the above code I get an error,

> The multi-part identifier "tab.val_4" could not be bound

Comment: Please ask me in the comments if the question is not understandable or you need some clarification

Comment: You can use *from_table_name*  only in DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement.  Consider updating `@Temp `after INSERT  provided you have UNIQUE keys in both `@Temp`  and  `table_2`.

Answer (score 2):

`MERGE` statement (instead of `INSERT`) can do this:

```
MERGE INTO table_1 t1
USING (
    select  
         val_1 as col1,
         val_2 as col2,
         val_3 as col3,
         val_4 as col4
    from table_2 tab 
    where tab.something > 0
) t2
   on 1=2 -- so that all t2 records are treated as 'no match'
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (col1, col2, col3)
    values (t2.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.col1, INSERTED.col2, INSERTED.col3, t2.col4
  INTO @Temp (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
;
```

I have not tested it extensively..

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 INSERT statements:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (col_1 INT, col_2 INT, col_3 INT, col_4 INT);


INSERT INTO @Temp(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
SELECT tab.val_1,
    tab.val_2,
    tab.val_3,
    tab.val_4
FROM table_2 AS tab
WHERE tab.something > 0;

INSERT INTO table_1(col_1, col_2, col_3)
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3
FROM @Temp;
```