MERGE clause detecting changes but not inserting latest values
I am trying to implement SCD type 2 using MERGE statement in SQL Server.
I have written the following code:
INSERT INTO Dim_Customer (Customer_Internal_ID, Customer_Name,
                          Price_Level, INS_TS, Is_active)
    SELECT
        Internal_ID, Name,
        Price_Level, GETDATE(), 1
    FROM
        (MERGE Dim_Customer AS T 
         USING (SELECT
                    Internal_ID, NULLIF(Name, '') Name,
                    NULLIF(Price_Level, '') Price_Level
                FROM
                    Stg_Customer) AS S ON T.Customer_Internal_ID = S.Internal_ID
         WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
             INSERT (Customer_Internal_ID, Customer_Name,
                     Price_Level, INS_TS, Is_active)
             VALUES (S.Internal_ID, S.Name,
                     S.Price_Level, GETDATE(), 1)

         WHEN MATCHED AND T.Is_active = 1
                      AND (ISNULL(T.Customer_Name, '') <> ISNULL(S.Name, '')
                           OR ISNULL(T.Price_Level, '') <> ISNULL(S.Price_Level, '')) 
             THEN
                 UPDATE
                 SET T.Is_active = 0 
                 OUTPUT S.Internal_ID, S.Name, S.Price_Level, $ACTION AS Merge_Action
        ) MRG
    WHERE
        MRG.Merge_Action = 'UPDATE';

For few records it is detecting the changes, but instead of updating with the new value it is inserting the same values again and marking Is_active = 1.
Staging has everything in VARCHAR.
Price_Level has values like following:
Tier 3 (38% Discount)
Tier 4 (35% Discount) etc.

I tried to implement SCD type 2 using MERGE clause, but it is not working for few records.

Why are you doing an insert with nested merge?  If you want to insert the results of the merge (delete, insert, update) you can use the OUTPUT clause for the merge and get if it was inserted, updated, deleted and save somewhere.

@Brad Can you please share relevant links/ pseudo code?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70937069/combining-data-with-select-clause-with-output-clause
Check this out but you can insert into a real table not just a temp table as in this example.
